# Codeigniter - How to Set Value Of Selected Option That Populated Data From Database

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I know maybe my question is very familiar, but i am a newbie in Codeigniter. I have been already implement a solution through searching in Stackoverflow, but the problem it's still persists. So i decided to ask again this question, through this forum.

I am trying to insert a data into a PostgreSQL table, but the error tells me that i have a **null value** in my query. I see thats the value that comes from option is not has any value.

This is my code.

**Model**

```
<?php
    class M_Item extends CI_Model{
        public function show_data(){
            return $this->db->get('tb_item');
        }

        public function add_item($data){
            $this->db->insert('tb_item', $data);
        }

        public function delete_item($where){
            $this->db->delete('tb_item', $where);
        }

        public function edit_item($where, $table){
            return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
        }

        public function update_item($where, $data, $table){
            $this->db->where($where);
            $this->db->update($table, $data);
        }

        public function getAllItemName(){
            $query = $this->db->query('select item_name from tb_item;');
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
?>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
    class Purchase extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model(['m_purchase','m_inventory','m_item','m_grid','m_vendor']);
            $this->load->helper(['string','form']);
        }

        // Show index
        public function index(){
            $data['purchase'] = $this->m_purchase->show_data()->result();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('pages/transaksi/v_purchase', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        // Show form for input vendor
        public function form_create(){
            $item = $this->m_item->getAllItemName();
            $grid = $this->m_grid->getAllGridName();
            $vendor = $this->m_vendor->getAllVendorName();

            $data = array(
                'item' => $item,
                'grid' => $grid,
                'vendor' => $vendor
            );

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('pages/transaksi/v_purchase_create', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

//method add vendor
        public function add(){

            $purchase_item = new stdClass();
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
            $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            // User as dummy
            $userId = 1;


            $purchase_number = $this->input->post('purchase_id');
            $purchase_item = $this->input->post('item_id');
            $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
            $grid = $this->input->post('grid_id');
            $vendor = $this->input->post('vendor_id');

            $data = array(
                'purchase_id' => $purchase_number,
                'purchase_time' => $now,
                'item_id' => $purchase_item,
                'quantity' => (int)$quantity,
                'grid_id' => $grid,
                'vendor_id' => $vendor,
                'user_id' => $userId
            );

            $dataStock = array(
                'item_id' => $purchase_item,
                'grid_id' => $grid,
                'stock' => $quantity,
                'last_update' => $now
            );

            $this->db->trans_start();
            $this->m_purchase->add_purchase($data, 'tb_purchase');
            $this->m_inventory->updateStock($dataStock, 'tb_inventory');
            $this->db->trans_complete();
            if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
                throw 
                $message = "Gagal Simpan data";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            } else {
                $success = "Sukses Simpan Data";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$success');</script>";
                redirect('pages/transaksi/purchase/index');
            }


        }

    //Another Code hiding
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="">Purchase Item</label>
   <select name="item_id" id="item_id" class="form-control">
   <?php foreach ($item as $i) :{
    echo "<option value='".$i->item_id."'>".$i->item_name."</option>";
   }
   endforeach; ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

**Error Result**

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "" LINE 1: ... VALUES ('PURCHASEOMS101', '2020-01-05 16:12:04', '', 100, '... ^

INSERT INTO "tb_purchase" ("purchase_id", "purchase_time", "item_id", "quantity", "grid_id", "vendor_id", "user_id") VALUES ('PURCHASEOMS101', '2020-01-05 16:12:04', '', 100, '', '', 1)
```

I was expected that the query has inserting some data to the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST);` at the start of your add() func. to see what you are getting. Also check your html when generated (view source) that its populating the option values well (guessing the problem is there). And don't mix the `foreach` open/closes. Either use `{...}` or `: ... endforeach;`

Comment: thanks for the reply @Mikeyhun . before the save button clicked i ve been checked the console with dev tools, and i get something like this. ``` A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$item_id Filename: transaksi/v_purchase_create.php Line Number: 54 <option value="">Indomie Ayam Bawang</option> ``` and this is the var_dump result ``` array(5) { ["purchase_id"]=> string(14) "PURCHASEOMS101" ["item_id"]=> string(0) "" ["quantity"]=> string(3) "100" ["vendor_id"]=> string(0) "" ["grid_id"]=> string(0) "" } ```

Comment: Yeah it looks like there's some problem with your `getAllItemName()` querry. Try `var_dump($item);` in `form_create()` after it has run.

EDIT: Never mind found your error: in `getAllItemName()` function you only selecting `item_name` and you need `item_id` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some searching and implementation, i found a solution for this case, i made a change on 2 file, the controller and the view

**Purchase Controller**

```
// Show form for input purchase
        public function form_create(){  
            $data['item'] = $this->m_item->show_data()->result();
            $data['grid'] = $this->m_grid->show_data()->result();
            $data['vendor'] = $this->m_vendor->show_data()->result();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('pages/transaksi/v_purchase_create', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        //method add vendor
        public function add(){
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
            $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            // User as dummy
            $userId = 1;

            $purchase_number = $this->input->post('purchase_id');
            $purchase_item = $this->input->post('purchase_item');
            $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
            $grid = $this->input->post('grid_id');
            $vendor = $this->input->post('vendor_id');

            $data = array(
                'purchase_id' => $purchase_number,
                'purchase_time' => $now,
                'item_id' => (int) $purchase_item,
                'quantity' => (int) $quantity,
                'grid_id' => (int) $grid,
                'vendor_id' => (int) $vendor,
                'user_id' => $userId
            );

            $dataStock = array(
                'item_id' => $purchase_item,
                'grid_id' => $grid,
                'stock' => $quantity,
                'last_update' => $now
            );

            $this->db->trans_start();
            $this->m_purchase->add_purchase($data, 'tb_purchase');
            $this->m_inventory->updateStock($dataStock, 'tb_inventory');
            $this->db->trans_complete();
            if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
                throw 
                $message = "Gagal Simpan data";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            } else {
                $success = "Sukses Simpan Data";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$success');</script>";
                redirect('pages/transaksi/purchase/index');
            }


        }

//another code hiding
```

**V_Purchase_Create**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="">Purchase Item</label>
      <select name="purchase_item" id="item_id" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach($item as $row):?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row->item_id;?>"><?php echo $row->item_name;?> 
          </option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
      </select>
</div>
```

So maybe this is not the best practice, (maybe you can do something like this with AJAX) but i think it's oke, thanks to @mikeyhun for answering my question, happy coding!!